Constrain generic type in library based on user config
I'm writing a package which will be an extension of another package. The JavaScript is now fully functional, but I want to add typescript library files describing it (Aside: I've never written anything in TypeScript, so may have basic thinking errors in what follows). The issue I'm facing is, most of my operations rely on the user "telling me" the name of certain keys.
The question is, how do I get the manual *.d.ts files to reflect that user configuration?
(If not obvious from above, the "user" is someone writing a JS/TS program using my package as a dependency.)
There are more complicated scenarios if an argument is optional, or if what they're configuring depends on previous configuration in the third-party package, but, in it's simplest form, the way the JS currently works is that my main function takes a config arg, and then I pass that around internally to other functions which I return as methods for external use:
// File: index.mjs
import { myMethod } from './methods.mjs';
export class MyExtension {
    constructor(idFieldName) {
        this.idFieldName = idFieldName;
    }

    myMethod = (methodArgs) => return myMethod.call(this, {...methodArgs, idFieldName: this.idFieldName});
}

and then I do things in the method which drive the args based on the top level config:
// File: my-method.mjs
export function myMethod({ arg1, arg2, idFieldName }) {
    if (! arg2[idFieldName]) throw new Error(`${idFieldName}` is required in arg2!}
}

As I said, the JS works fine (though, NB, it's not currently written as a class; the above is just for simplified exposition here). But now I want to write the typescript library, so that when the user uses the module in writing their own code, they can get
const extension = new MyExtension('foo');
const client = new External.with(extension);

const someValue = client.myMethod('hello', { bar: '42' });
// some error or warning like ts error 'bar' is not a valid key for arg2!
// even better, they'd get a type hint to autocomplete `foo` instead of `bar`

Ultimately, I will probably re-write the whole thing in TypeScript, but I want to get there incrementally, and getting the library files working seems like a good start (and seems more important for the user). To do that, I need to be able to get something like this:
// File: types.d.ts
interface MyMethodArgs<IdFieldName> {
    arg1: string;
    arg2: { [IdFieldName]: string };
}

Things I've considered to make this work:

Write a generic definition for the entry point function, (this feels easiest, but I don't know how to do it)
Have the user configure the parameters in an environment variable / config file, and import them into *.d.ts
mumble mumble mumble something with symbols mumble mumble
write some script the user has to run after installation that "compiles" my *.d.ts files with the right parameters (this seems hardest, but if it's what needs to be done...)

ISTM this must be a not-uncommon problem, so I'm hoping there's some "standard" way of achieving it, and I'm just not aware of it.
Thanks for any suggestions, even if not a complete solution, just so I'm pointed in the right direction!

I'd love to see a self-contained [mre] here that shows a working toy example of how it behaves without the types, and then we could play around with it and make show how types would work. Otherwise we're inviting for suggestions that the suggester hasn't tested. I mean, I could imagine something like this approach, but I had to guess a lot more than I feel comfortable with. Please consider [edit]ing to make this a little more specific so it's a good fit for SO.

This can probably be made more "minimal", but it's about as good as I can get while still reproducing the structure I'm actually using, and showing what I'm trying to accomplish. LMK if it works for you, and I'll edit the question to include it: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/add-ts-extension-2ktnpk

Hmm, I looked at it and it's not clicking for me. I don't understand what people are supposed to do with any of those types. I think I need to see something concrete and some uses of it. I'll look again later, maybe it'll make more sense to me then.

OK. Also if helpful, I can give an example of the real project (from the published NPM package) working; though without types :)

I don't get this example... is it a typo that you're calling client.myMethod('hello', { bar: '42' }); instead of client.myMethod({arg1: 'hello', arg2: { bar: '42' }});? I don't see anywhere in this example where ordered parameters would be spread or destructured into our out of an object.

(see prev comment) Assuming you're not really spreading params into arrays or vice versa, I'd say this approach is how I'd look at giving types to your stuff. But I don't know if that will work because of whatever External is. Is this close to something useful for you? I'm happy to write up an answer but I don't know if this is what you're talking about.
